# Batch File Filter loop output

Tags: batch-file, filter, nested-for-loop

The code runs a very simple process of pinging multiple addresses endlessy and outputting the results to a log file until manually stopped.

```
@echo off
title ping_logger
set d1=%date:~4%
set d2=%d1:/=-%
set t1=%time::=.%
set t2=%t1: =%
set host=X.X.X.1;X.X.X.162
set hostname=%host:;=+%
set pinghostname=%host:;= and %
set logfile=Log_%hostname%_%ComputerName%_%d2%_%t2%.csv
setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set counter=0
for %%A IN (%host%) DO (
    set /a counter+=1
)
endlocal && set counter=%counter%
echo Target Host(s) = %host%>%logfile%
echo Pinging %pinghostname% with 32 bytes of data: >>%logfile%
timeout %counter% >NUL
:Ping
FOR %%A IN (%host%) DO (
    for /F "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %%A -n 1 ') do (
        echo %date:~4%, %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A>>%logfile%
        echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A
    )
)
IF (%counter% LSS 2)  timeout 1 >NUL
GOTO Ping
```

The output is capturing too much into the log file.  I'm looking to only get the first line from each response such as the highlighted lines

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:DoPing
FOR %%A IN (%host%) DO (
    set "pung="
    for /F "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %%A -n 1 ') do  if not defined pung (
        echo %date:~4%, %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A>>%logfile%
        echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A
        set "pung=Y"
    )
)
IF (%counter% LSS 2)  timeout 1 >NUL
GOTO DoPing
```

(I'm allergic to using keywords/executable names as labels)

Simply set a flag value `pung` to *nothing* so that it is undefined when the `ping`s start. On reporting the first line, set `pung` to non-empty, so it is then `defined` and the remining report lines are suppressed.

Next loop of `%%A` clears `pung` before issuing the ping for the next host...

---

Another way:

```
:DoPing
FOR %%A IN (%host%) DO (
    for /F "tokens=1* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %%A -n 1 ') do if "%%A" == "Reply" (
        echo %date:~4%, %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A %%B>>%logfile%
        echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%, %%A %%B
    )
)
IF (%counter% LSS 2)  timeout 1 >NUL
GOTO DoPing
```

This time, see whether the first token is the string `Reply` and only write the report if this is so.